# Mysql inner query to get sum of amount

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I have three tables which are interlinked :

1) First is **order** table that contains 2 columns, id and vendor_id
2) Second table is **order_products** that contains product detail of **order** table and has columns order_id (foreign key of id from order table) and product_id.
3) Third table is **vendors_product** that contains prices of products for different vendor like vendor_1 has $10 for product_a and vendor_2 has $20 for product_a so each vendor has different prices of same products. This table has columns, vendor_id (foreign key of vendor_id from order table), product_id (foreign key of product_id from order_products table) and product_amount columns

Now I want to get the sum of **product_amount** for all order and should be based on vendor of each order.

I tried this by using below query but I couldn't get the result

```
SELECT
    a.id, a.vendor_id, (
    SELECT
        SUM(product_amount)
    FROM
        vendors_product
    WHERE
        vendor_id = a.vendor_id
        AND product_id IN (
            SELECT
                product_id
            FROM
                order_products
            WHERE
                order_id = a.id
        )
    ) as total_price
FROM
    `order` a
```

Can somebody help me out ???

Comment: For sanity's sake, do not use reserved words as table/column identifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT o.id, o.vendor_id, SUM(product_amount) product_amount
FROM `order` o 
INNER JOIN order_products op ON o.id = op.order_id 
INNER JOIN vendors_product vp ON a.vendor_id = vp.vendor_id AND op.product_id = vp.product_id
GROUP BY o.id, o.vendor_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.vendor_id, SUM(product_amount) AS 'product amount'
FROM `order` a 
INNER JOIN order_products vp1 ON a.id = vp1.order_id 
INNER JOIN vendors_product vp2 ON a.vendor_id = vp2.vendor_id AND vp1.product_id = vp2.product_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.vendor_id
```

Comment: yes, it works but it shows the total product amount of all vendor product, it is not associated with order_products table. I want the sum of only product amount that a order has but calculation should be based of vendor's product_amount.